# Equation of the tangent line

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the tangent line at $$x=3$$
assuming that $$f(3)=5$$ $$and$$ $$f'(3)=2$$

---

The answer is  $y=2x-1$ but I need to know the procedure.

Comment: To start off, you can use the "point-slope" form for the equation of the line, $ \ y - y_0 = m \ (x - x_0) \ . $  What is the slope of the tangent line?  What are the coordinates of the given point on the curve for the (unknown) function $ \ y = f(x) \ $ ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- The equation of a line is $y=m+c$ where $(x,y)$ is a coordinate on the line and $m$ is the gradient.
- To find the gradient you find the derivative of $f(x)$ then plug the $x$ coordinate into $f'(x)$ to get $m$.
- You were given $x=3$ and $f(3)=5$ this $\implies$ that the tangent runs through the coordinate $(3,5)$.
- You also have the value of the derivative at $x=3$, this $\implies$ that the gradient is $2$.
- Using $y=mx+c$, $m=2$ and the coordinate $(3,5)$ you can find $c$ and then you have your equation.
  $$5=3(2)+c\implies 5-6=c\implies c=-1$$
  And thus your equation is $y=2x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

You know the slope at $3$ is $2$ given by $f'(3)=2 \Rightarrow y-5=2(x-3)$ is your desired line equation.

Answer (score 0):

Well a tangent line is given by a linear equation of form $ax+b$
Using $5=3a+b$ and $a=2$(because the derivative of $ax+b$ is equal to $a$)
This is equal to $5=6+b,b=-1$ so the function is $2x-1$